# IERC20 public declaration with another address?

Tags: ethereum, solidity

I am new to solidity, but checking through a specific contract I found the following line of code in the IERC20 declaration:

IERC20 public "TOKEN NAME" = IERC20("THE ADDRESS OF ANOTHER CONTRACT");

This code was found in a contract that is effectively a fork of another project, but the developers say they are unrelated. Of course, people are just FOMO into the token - I know this forum here is not for this type of discussion so I'll abstain from the same.

However, from a solidity coding perspective, why would one write this line of code directly referencing another contract address (the forked address) when making the IERC20 declaration - what does this do, is there a purpose to this?

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that this is easier and more reliable. Alternatively, you can pass this address in constructor parameters, or provide a special method to set it.

Comment: But why use another contract's address that should be unrelated to this project?

Answer (score 0):

The `IERC20` is an interface that defines expected functions arguments and return values.

**It helps validating whether the caller is passing correct data types, amount of arguments, and helps parsing the returned data to expected types.**

---

Let's show it on a very simple interface

```
interface IGame {
    function play(uint256 randomNumber) returns (bool won);
}
```

Elsewhere in your contract, you define a variable that uses this interface

```
IGame game = Game("0xthe_game_address");
```

You can then directly call the other contract's methods defined in the interface and pass the return values to your variables.

```
bool didIWin = game.play(1);
```

The call would fail if the game contract didn't have the `play` method or didn't return any value (plus in few other cases).

---

As for why is the address hardcoded, it's probably just to simplify the development as Mad Jackal already said in their answer.

One more plausible reason in some cases is to gain more trust by showing users that the contract admins are not able to cheat you by changing the destination address (possibly to a contract made by them doing whatever they want).

Edit: If the another contract's address is really unrelated and useless (meaning, the fork is not calling it), it's probably just a human error and the developer forgot to remove it.